# Obtaining Failed Login Attempts Count in Azure B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am developing a login journey using Azure B2C Custom Policy, and I have encountered a requirement where I need to implement a Google reCAPTCHA feature if a user fails to log in correctly three times consecutively. I have reviewed the official Microsoft sample on integrating reCAPTCHA into Azure B2C Custom Policy, which provides guidance on implementing the reCAPTCHA functionality. However, I am unsure about how to retrieve the count of failed login attempts from the custom policy itself.

While I am aware that the frontend can potentially track the number of failed login attempts, I believe it would be more secure and reliable to handle this logic on the backend side. Therefore, I am seeking assistance on how to obtain the count of failed login attempts within the Azure B2C Custom Policy, specifically identifying when the user has made their third unsuccessful login attempt.